# Trying to use the new Receipt Validation Programming of iOS and stopping at step 1

Tags: ios, mkstorekit

I am trying to switch from using the transactionReceipt to the receipt returned from the appStoreReceiptURL as in the Apple's:
[Receipt Validation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateLocally.html)

Yet I am stuck at compiling the output of the asn1c command. Apart from the host of angled references to header files I had to switch individually to quotes, there are a number of errors connected to features evidently not available on iOS. They seem to be connected to the finite() function and the DEBUG command. Here are two examples:

```
if(!finite(d)) { //solved with isfinite()
```

and

```
/* Debug output function */
static inline void
DEBUG(const char *fmt, ...) {
    va_list ap;
    if(!opt_debug) return;
    fprintf(stderr, "AD: ");
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    vfprintf(stderr, fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    fprintf(stderr, "\n");
 }
```

What should I substitute them with?

Comment: You want to see my project on github - https://github.com/rmaddy/VerifyStoreReceiptiOS

Comment: I downloaded it, but I miss all openssl libraries, and at any rate extracting the piece I need from that would be huge task. The Apple instructions seem clear, if only I could rid of those compilation errors.

Comment: At any rate the finite business I managed to fix by substituting finite() with isfinite(). Now I miss how to rendere DEBUG().

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed the whole: the procedure encompassed:

1) changing most '<..>'includes to '"..."' (the compiler gives hints)
2) changing the name of function DEBUG to debug, what prompted "something" to turn it to:

```
void ASN_DEBUG_f(const char *fmt, ...);
void ASN_DEBUG_f(const char *fmt, ...) {
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    vfprintf(stderr, fmt, ap);
    fprintf(stderr, "\n");
    va_end(ap);
}
```

3) And finally remove the sample.c file containing another main function, and two README files.

Done those the program compiles without problems.